# How do I play blu-ray discs in Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS?

Tags: vlc, media, blu-ray

From search I can see that this question has arisen a few times in the past.  But the answers are all old and/or out-of-date.  The "official" documentation seems to have been written back in *2010*, unless I'm looking at the wrong page:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/BluRayAndHDDVD

I've also read some suggestions to install "libbluray1"; but that library is not available for 20.04 LTS.  (It was available for 16.04.)  There is a "libbluray2", which I have.

On my system I have VLC installed from the ubuntu-focal-universe, and MakeMKV from snap.  My external drive is a Pioneer BDR-XD05S (described on the box as a Blu-ray Burner), which I have plugged in to a USB port.  When I insert a standard DVD into the drive, both VLC and MakeMKV read the drive fine.

When I insert a blu-ray, VLC says it's "unable to open the MRL 'bluray:///dev/sr0'. Check the log for details."  Syslog has this:

```
Mar 30 15:29:49 jim-NUC7i5BNH budgie-panel.desktop[168403]: disc.c:323: failed opening UDF image /dev/sr0
Mar 30 15:29:49 jim-NUC7i5BNH budgie-panel.desktop[168403]: disc.c:424: error opening file BDMV/index.bdmv
Mar 30 15:29:49 jim-NUC7i5BNH budgie-panel.desktop[168403]: disc.c:424: error opening file BDMV/BACKUP/index.bdmv
Mar 30 15:29:49 jim-NUC7i5BNH budgie-panel.desktop[168403]: bluray.c:2585: nav_get_title_list(/dev/sr0/) failed
```

With MakeMKV, the drive spins for a while and then MakeMKV says there's "No disc inserted".

For reference, I have some blu-ray libraries installed:

```
$ apt search libbluray
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libbluray-bdj/focal,focal,now 1:1.2.0-1 all [installed]
  Blu-ray Disc Java support library (BD-J library)

libbluray-bin/focal,now 1:1.2.0-1 amd64 [installed]
  Blu-ray disc playback support library (tools)

libbluray-dev/focal 1:1.2.0-1 amd64
  Blu-ray disc playback support library (development files)

libbluray-doc/focal,focal 1:1.2.0-1 all
  Blu-ray disc playback support library (documentation)

libbluray2/focal,now 1:1.2.0-1 amd64 [installed]
  Blu-ray disc playback support library (shared library)
```

There IS a "KEYDB.cfg" file in my ~/.config directory.

How do I troubleshoot this?  Do I need to install MakeMLV from source?

Comment: Are you using the supplied USB cable which is a micro-usb on the drive side to two standard type-a usb connectors? As Pioneer states in manual `In some cases, the use of a single USB port may be insufficient for normal operation.Use two USB ports for power enhancement.` Is it a standard HD Blu-ray or a 4k UHD Blu-ray? Have you tried other different Blu-ray disks?

Comment: Yep, I *am* using the double-cable that came with the drive.

I only have standard blu-ray discs.  I've used a few different discs (Die Hard, Casino Royale), Constantine, all with the exact same result.

Comment: To me this sounds like a hardware (drive) problem. I don't think it's a VLC issue or a MakeMKV issue. Without any of the extra libraries MakeMKV should be able to see and open the disk. And the errors you are seeing are what you get when VLC tries to open a Blu-ray when the drive is empty/ejected. Do a `sudo dmesg -w` in a terminal then see if any relevant messages/errors appear when you insert a Blu-ray. Check/update the drive firmware or try/buy another drive.

Comment: Welp – I didn't want to believe it was hardware.  It's working fine for standard DVDs!  But I tried the drive on my wife's Windows laptop, and it failed to read three different blu-rays.  We may have found the culprit  :-/

Comment: Got a new drive, an LG BP60NB10 marked-down off Amazon Warehouse.  Works fine.  What do I do with this question?  Withdraw it?  Edit it to show that the problem was hardware?  Other?